# Have MySQL and MariaDB on the same server using apt?

Tags: apt, mysql, 19.10, mariadb

Looking to have a local testing server using Ubuntu.

I would like to have both MySQL and MariaDB on this server, at the same time (Different ports, obviously).

Is it possible to install both using Apt? I notice if I install one it wants to remove the other.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using docker. Makes it easier and easier to backup. And no mariadb and mysql will cancel eachother out. Official document on installing mariadb from source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/ They used centos but the same will work on Ubuntu.

Comment: As in a docker for MySQL and one for MariaDB?