# Why does Ubuntu prohibit installing both MySQL and MariaDB via Apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, mariadb

Something I've seen stump users (including myself) is that Apt won't allow both MySQL and MariaDB to be installed.  For instance, here's a nearly 3-year-old [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194366/have-mysql-and-mariadb-on-the-same-server-using-apt) on the topic, still unanswered.

As a concrete description of the problem, consider Ubuntu 22.04.  If I have MySQL installed using Apt, and I then attempt to install the MariaDB package, Apt will demand the removal of MySQL:

```
# MySQL 8.0 is installed:
$ apt-cache policy mysql-server-8.0 
mysql-server-8.0:
  Installed: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  ...

# MariaDB 10.6 is not installed:
$ apt-cache policy mariadb-server-10.6 
mariadb-server-10.6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:10.6.7-2ubuntu1.1
  ...

# Attempt to install MariaDB 10.6:
$ sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.6 
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  galera-4 gawk libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl
  libsigsegv2 libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-client-10.6
  mariadb-client-core-10.6 mariadb-server-core-10.6
...
# MySQL packages are removed:
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server mysql-server-8.0
  mysql-server-core-8.0
...
```

I've never heard anyone give a good reason for this.  MySQL and MariaDB are quite similar, but that doesn't automatically preclude them from co-existing.  In fact, multiple versions of MySQL itself can co-exist on the same machine, as explained by [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-servers.html).  And as explained by [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/), there's no reason one of those multiple versions can't be an instance of MariaDB.

So if there's no fundamental reason I can't have MySQL and MariaDB installed at the same time, why does Apt insist on treating these as mutually exclusive?

Comment: @user535733 That seems like a good thread to follow.  Do you know an example of one of the overlapping files off the top of your head?

Comment: everything in `/var/lib/mysql`  and `/etc/my.conf`. Mariadb is a drop in replacement so for all intent and purpose you need to see MariaDB as another MySQL version.

Comment: You should consider containers if you intend to run multiple databases on a single installation.

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple MySQLs but only ONE installed using apt. For installing through apt MariaDB is the same as a MySQL install: MariaDB is a drop-in replacement and the 2 use the same library names and files (both in `/var/lib/mysql` and `/etc/mysql/my.conf`). Maybe in the future this might change.

But like you can install more versions MySQL in for instance /opt and even have those run at the same time using another port you can also add more than 1 MariaDB to all those MySQL installs in /opt and using its own port. Or install more than one using the same port having only 1 active at a time.

Comment: I don't see why using the same libraries is an obstacle.  That's what libraries are for, in fact.  To abstract the problem, consider packages `mysql` and `mariadb`, representing the obvious programs, and a third package `sql-libs`, representing the shared libraries.  Once `mysql` and its dependency `sql-libs` is installed, there's no reason another package `mariadb` can't be installed simultaneously to use the same `sql-libs`.

Comment: @DarienMarks They are "the same" libraries in sense of file names/paths, but they are different in sense of the file **contents**. So they are in fact **conflicting** libraries. MySQL and MariaDB cannot use a common set of libraries as you suggest, because both packages contain two different versions of "the same" (in sense of names) libraries. They are just designed so. So how to decide which version to use? If you use version for MySQL, it may work improperly with MariaDB and vice versa.

Comment: Hmm I changed it to "library names" :)