# Problems installing MariaDB on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, mariadb

```
root@vmi1433468:~# sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to 
be installed
mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to 
be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I need help please

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some MySQL packages installed on your system. MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL and both use the same library names and files (both in `/var/lib/mysql` and `/etc/mysql/my.conf`). Check this post: [Why does Ubuntu prohibit installing both MySQL and MariaDB via apt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1428670/1157209) for more details.

Use `apt list --installed | grep mysql` and look for `mysql-server`, `mysql-client-8.0` and other similar packages.

If you want to install MariaDB, you will have to uninstall these. You can remove them manually one by one or use `apt` with wildcard(`*`) like this:

```
sudo apt remove mysql*
sudo apt autoremove
```